# Zend_Form not rendering

Tags: php, linux, render, zend-form

Folks, I'm having some problems making a form render/display in my webpage. Well, it works fine in my local server, but once I use the same code in a remote server, the webpage displays fine, but the form is missing.

**Localhost:**

OS: Win 7

PHP: 5.3.8

Apache: 2.2.21

Zend: 1.11.3

**Remote Server:**

OS: Linux CentOS release 5.5
PHP: 5.3.8

Apache: 2.2.3

Zend: 1.11.3

**FeedbackForm.php**

> class forms_FeedbackForm extends Zend_Form {
>
> public function init() {
>
> $this->setAction('')->setMethod('post')->setName('feedbackForm');
>
> $feedback = new Zend_Form_Element_Textarea('feedback');
>
> $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Button('submitButton');
>
> $this->addElement($feedback)->addElement($submit);
> }
> }

**IndexController.php**

> class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
>
> public function indexAction()   {
>
> $form = new forms_FeedbackForm();
>
> ```
>   $this->view->form = $form;
> ```
>
> } }

**index.phtml**

> echo $this->form;

However, if I replace the echo statement with print_r($this->form), I see the object details with both servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a capital for your class: Forms_FeedbackForm instead of forms_FeedbackForm. The autoloader doesn't find it on Linux.

Generally when problems like this occure between Linux and Windows servers it's a capital problem. Linux is case sensitive, windows isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine.
I suggest you set display exceptions on in your application.ini:

resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1 
And make sure your error view displays exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, but that didn't do anything either. Still no form!

Comment: I can see the form object details if I do a print_r() instead of echo

Comment: what do you see when you do: echo $this->form->render(); ?

Comment: Same. Still so form on Linux, and the localhost still works fine.

Comment: Btw, just did a diff on the form objects outputted with print_r() and they are exactly the same.

Comment: Also nothing showing up in the source of your html? Try to set display_errors = 1 in your application.ini file.

Comment: I used Firebug to inspect the HTML and I see no form... display_errors did't do it either.

Comment: I checked the Apache error log file and I found an error with one of the form filters (which I didn't bother adding above)... I was using the incorrect case. Not sure why it behaved differently in Windows, but oh well... Thanks for your help!

Comment: You file system in linux is case sensitive and windows not, that's why it couldn't be found in linux and not in windows. Great you did find it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your view looks like `<?php echo $this->form; ?>`, otherwise, the PHP won't actually execute.

Comment: I do have the php tags on there, just forgot to add them above.